# Copy to clipboard limitation

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, powerpoint, copy-paste

As many other question about this topic, I still didn't find something that could avoid my issue.

I'd like to know what are the limitations of the clipboard in term of copy paste processing in time and restrict its copy paste functionality for specific usage and program ID.

Because, I've been developping a software for my company that takes a template in Word/Excel and PowerPoint to make auto generated reports by replacing the picture every day and pasting the new graph and the picture which are in the template.

But, I'm afraid, because it seems to exist some limitations about the copy to clipboard

```
CopyBitmapToClipboard

ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial()
```

When I copy a table/image into my clipboard and paste it in Word/Excel/PowerPoint it is fine, but if I have now 10 parallel reports which are generated at the same time and use the mechanism of copy paste, it will happen that it will copy it in the Word/Excel/PowerPoint that is currently being used by another report.

Taking in consideration, I have 1 document, and the copy to clipboard of a table that is huge into powerpoint, would take the best case 1 second( which doesn't ), this would mean that in 1 day, I can generate a maximum of

```
1 copy paste procedure = 1 second

1minute = 60 second means 60 copy paste

1hour = 60min x 60 copy paste

1day = 24hours x 3600 copy paste
```

Means I have a total of **86400** copy paste/reports. Which is impossible. A document will never take minimum of 1 second to be complete( for reports which are about 20 pages, powerpoint with 30 slides, excel worksheet with 6sheets ). How to avoid that the content copied into clipboard will be pasted in the wrong document, since both documents use the paste fonction.

So, I'd like to know, if it is possible to give a reference into my clipboard, to tell him, to copy only the content inside his word/excel/powerpoint and not to copy what I just copied doing CTRL+C and to do CTRL+V in the wrong document?

At the moment, we have about 50 reports daily to generate( taking in consideration that few months ago we had 2 reports to generate ), which are scheduled in interval of 5 minutes, but what will happen the day we will have 86400 daily reports to generate? The copy paste fonction will screw up all reports and paste in the wrong report. I might not be there to assist it, but I'd like to prevent that impact.

I was writing my software in C#/.NET, but I can't write inside it to catch if a current schedule/report is being generated, because I run a **.bat** that does the creation of the report with the program I wrote.

**Edited:
Content of my **.bat** is: 
    myprogram.exe /objectsourceprogram="" /sourcefile="my template.doc/xls/ppt" /destinationfile="my destination.doc/xls/ppt"

I'm only scheduling my batch file, the only thing that can be done is, waiting that one scheduling is being completed before starting the next one, but this will create intervales

Comment: Don't you have a better option then copy-pasting? Maybe you can use API of both applications to move data from one to another.

Comment: You could use OLE to insert the charts/etc rather than copying/pasting

Comment: I'm saving pictures in a temporary file which helps me to avoid that copy paste procedure, but tables are copied in clipboard, because my company wants me to generate on the other side for PowerPoint again a real table instead of images. I'm using NetOffice( kind of Microsoft way of handing it ).

Comment: @mike27015 why not just build the table directly in PPT from the data in Excel? VBA for PPT tables is not terribly difficult to navigate, if you'd like I can post an example.

Comment: @DavidZemens I don't implement any code for VBA. Reason? You create again and again the same code in the VBA, which is again manually work, that costs time, to avoid. As mention the issue will be in the future for the copy paste procedure, when there will be 86k reports per day to do. Tables, everything is done correctly, only the copy/paste won't work later when multiple documents are open, it will paste it in the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with auto-generated reports in Word and Excel as well. You're doing it the slow way, no wonder it's slow - .NET COM interop is quite slow as it its and then your process utilizes other threads, so now you have to take marshalling and synchronizing between threads since Office is single-threaded.

Copy/paste is a high-level, user function and you can use it as a hack but relying on it as a primary way of executing your task is a poor choice.

Better choice: Office APIs (VSTO, anyone?) - I'm pretty sure whatever you've come up with in terms of reports is reproducible through APIs. Beware - too many API calls and your functions can work slower.

Best choice: OpenXML SDK. The learning curve here will likely be steep since you're still using Copy/Paste but the payoff is that your document processing time will be reduced a couple  orders of magnitude.

Comment: I'm using NetOffice with VSTO. I think, I'll have a look at OpenXML SDK. I could overcome the copy paste process for images, while storing them in a temporary file, but tables-> will be saved as images too, but the company wants real tables in Excel/PowerPoint. By the way, table's input were initially HTML code that I copied into clipboard and generated real tables while pasting in Excel, where I copy the table into PowerPoint and create a real PowerPoint table according my Excel table.

Comment: If HTML is your source data you have a bigger problem since you can't reliably parse it. There's at least one library that does that - Aspose - but it's quite expensive. I'm using it to convert HTML templates to Word documents in my current project

Comment: No, the HTML is being paste in Word/Excel properly. In Word, it genereates the table and in Excel, while copying to clipboard and paste it generates a table from the HTML code and copy the range of table into powerpoint, read all rows, and create a new table which looks better. I used <b>Regex</b> to parse the HTML, and it works.
    item.SheetObject.CopyTableToClipboard(true); 
    string html = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
I'll have a look at OpenXML SDK and hope to find something to reduce the time lack.

Comment: OOXML can definitely do these tasks but not easily and quickly, especially when it comes to copy/paste between apps. It would be easier to create new objects in each app than to try copying them around - there are too many elements that can hold references to various parts of the documents. Find the OOXML tool for VS2008, it helps a lot understanding the premises

Comment: Thanks. I got the same reply from Microsoft. The best solution is http://openxmldeveloper.org/ Thanks for your help