# Renaming an excel(.xls) sheet without using interop and third party dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, xls

I am getting an excel(.xls) file as a byte array by rendering a local report(rdlc) and writing it into a location. I need to rename the excel sheets. I am not allowed to use third part dlls and interop. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at OOXML. There you can change the Excel file and avoid the Interop. It is the best solution to use and avoid Interops to do the job. Reasons, you can find a previous of my post [Copy to clipboard limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017052/copy-to-clipboard-limitation)

Comment: Does OOXML support .xls(Excel 2003) format ? Or is there any way to convert the .xls file I get from rdlc export to .xlsx format?

Comment: xls is not XML based format (unlike xlsx), so chances are this suggestion will not help OP.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Abhilash - Office 2003 isn't supported and does not support .xlsx which is a XML based format. If you want .xls support there are many alternatives which but any solution isn't being developed by the developer nor supported more then likely. If you can't use third-party solutions then you have to develop your own which will be tough if you can't use any third-party libraries at all.  Took entire teams of developers a half a decade to fully support .doc and .xls formats.  You can look at Open Office for help with creating your own .xls wrapper.

Comment: @Ramhound Office 2003 can work with xslx - check out [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-for-word-excel-and-powerpoint-HA010168676.aspx).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - While I forgot about the compatibility pack the rest of my statement is true.

Comment: @Abhilash True, forgot to mention that OOXML is supported only for .xlsx/.pptx and those new version of Office. For older, you might have to use interop or convert your documents to reccent ones.