# Reading images from Word files using C# Word API without using Clipboard

Tags: c#, bitmap, ms-word, office-interop, word-automation

I've been working on an application to read images from multiple word files and store them in one single word file using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in C#

**EDIT**: I also need to save a copy of the images on the file system, so I need the image in a Bitmap or similar object.

[This](http://pastebin.com/ymt2n4hT) is my implementation so far, which works fine:

```
        foreach (InlineShape shape in doc.InlineShapes)
        {
            shape.Range.Select();
            if (shape.Type == WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
            {
                doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.CopyAsPicture();
                ImageData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                object _ob1 = ImageData.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                bmp = (Bitmap)_ob1;
                images[i++] = bmp;
                /*
                bmp.Save("C:\\Users\\Akshay\\Pictures\\bitmaps\\test" + i.ToString() + ".bmp");
                */
            }
        }
```

I have:

- Selected the images as `InlineShapes`
- Copied the shape into Clipboard
- Stored the shape in the Clipboard in a `DataObject`
- Extracted the shape from the `DataObject` in `Bitmap` format and stored in a `Bitmap` object.

I've been told to refrain from using Clipboard in Word automation and use the Word APIs instead.
I've read up on it and found an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017211/2129255) stating the same.

I looked up many implementations of reading images from Word files on `MSDN`, `SO` etc. but could not find any without using clipboard.

How do I read images from Word files using the Word APIs from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` namespace alone without using Clipboard ?

Comment: is it the reason to not using clipboard is memory? if so, can't you dispose the object right after saving the image? Also remove the image\object from clipboard?

Comment: No, memory is not the issue behind not using the clipboard.
I want to stick on to the standard APIs provided by Interop Word rather than the clipboard workaround.

Comment: You state "...and store them in one single word file". If you really want to transfer the pictures directly to another Word document you should be able use TargetRange.FormattedText  = shape.Range.FormattedText

Comment: @CindyMeister I need the image in a Bitmap or similar object so that I can save a copy on the file system or do further manipulations as an image.

Comment: Also I have noticed that when Word copies the image to the Clipboard the image quality reduces.

Answer (score 0):

Word documents in the Office Open XML file format store images in Base64. So it should be possible to extract that information and convert/stream it to a file. You can access the information when the document is open in the Word application using the Range.WordOpenXML property.

```
string shapeBase64 = shape.Range.WordOpenXML;
```

This will return the entire Word Open XML in the flat file OPC format. In other words, it won't contain only the picture in Base64, but the entire zip package definition as XML that surrounds it. In my quick test, the tag the contains the actual Base64 is

```
<pkg:binaryData>
```

That's a child element of

```
<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/media/image1.jpg" pkg:contentType="image/jpeg" pkg:compression="store">
```

Note that it would also be possible for you to get the entire document's WordOpenXML in one step:

```
document.Content.WordOpenXML
```

but might then need to understand the way the InlineShapes in the document body are linked to the actual information in the "media" part.

And it would be possible, of course, to work directly with the Zip Package (using the Open XML SDK, perhaps) instead of opening the document in the Word.Application.

Comment: My implementation: http://pastebin.com/zF3sMm7D

I could read images using this method but only a few images within the document gave a valid XML representation.
The later XML strings neither conformed to the expected format, neither did they have the image data anywhere within it.

With some trial and error, I could find out that the images that could not be read were the ones which are not in the first page of the word document.
I could traverse through all the InlineShape pictures within the document but only the ones in the first page could give the valid XML string.

Comment: Well, that makes no sense... If it works for the first page the principle should work for all pages. It's possible you need to analyze the various graphical objects in the document, they may not all have been the same graphic type (bmp, png, jpg, wmf, etc.) or inserted the same way, etc. So the underlying XML may be different.